# combine two dd/mm/yyy string arrays into one while having the dates in order asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am calling two fields from two datatables (IncDate and ExpDate). They are stored as dd/MM/yyyy and when I make my sql call to the database, I use Order by Convert(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) to have the dates in order. I do this for each of my IncDate and ExpDae columns. 
I add each of these into a string array by using:

```
 var stringArr = Dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("IncDate")).ToArray();
var stringArr2 = Dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ExpDate")).ToArray();
```

The problem comes when I try to merge the two together into one string array. I do this by using:

```
string[] combined = stringArr.Concat(stringArr2).ToArray();
```

although this is just adding the dates randomly. I would like to have the dates combined and ordered in the combined string but I'm not sure how to do this.

So for example in IncDate I might have (01/03/2016, 02/03/2016, 03/03/2016, 06/03/2016) and in ExpDate i might have (02/03/2016, 03/03/2016, 04/03,2016) and when I combine them they should be in the order (01/03/2016, 02/03/2016, 02/03/2016, 03/03/2016, 03/03/2016, 04/03/2016, 06/03/2016)

Cheers in advance!

Comment: So how you want to combine them?

Comment: It would be better if you loaded them as `DateTime`.  Then it would be a simple `OrderBy(x=>x)` between the `Concat` and `ToArray`.  My rule of thumb is that the only time a date and\or time should be represented by a string is in a UI.

Comment: How do you want to order them? All of `A1`, then all of `A2`? Ordered by the date value?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Ok juharr I might do this but it would be a last resort as it would change everything else on the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You already have a CONVERT statement in your ORDER BY clause to convert the string-date to a real date. Use the same CONVERT statement in your SELECT clause.
2. Read the values as DateTimes instead of Strings:

   ```
    var dateArr = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>("IncDate")).ToArray();
   ```
3. After concatenating the arrays, use `OrderBy(x => x)` or `Array.Sort` to sort it.
4. Promise yourself to always use appropriate data types in your databases from now on instead of "hiding" dates in a string. That way, you won't need those CONVERT workarounds in the future.

General hint on working with "legacy" data stored in inappropriate data types: Convert the data to the real data type *as soon as possible* (note that we do that in Step 1), and, if required, convert it back *as late as possible*.

Comment: I'll try this now, thank you I know it was bad practice

Comment: Thank you for this I'm nearly there but when I try to add this data to my chart, it is saying "cannot implicitly convert data type system.datetime[] to string[]

Comment: @Stuart: Apparently, your chart expects data as strings. The *correct* way would be to modify your chart to accept datetime values instead. If that is not possible, you can convert your array back to strings with `var stringArr = dateArr.Select(d => d.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy")).ToArray();`

Comment: final query. when I run this statement "select CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103), IncCost from Incomings ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)" I am getting an error on this line "var dateArr = Dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>("IncDate")).ToArray();" saying that IncDate does not belong to the table

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the AS IncDate in my query